Who is affected by Obscured areas?

In a lightly obscured area, such as dim light, patchy fog, or moderate foliage, creatures have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight.


A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area.

So the ruling on heavily obscured seems to make sense, using the example of darkness, any creature which is not illuminated is hard to see (in most cases), but it can perfectly see any other creature which is well lit. Thus the effect only applies for creatures trying to see into the heavily obscured area.
I would expect the same kind of mechanic for lightly obscured areas. However, as written it seems to only affect creatures who are in the lightly obscured area. So viewing something in a lightly obscured area from either a normal or a heavily obscured area imposes no disadvantage, but viewing from inside the area to the outside does.
This seems strange to me; I would expect the rule for lightly obscured areas to read as follows
A lightly obscured area --such as dim light, patchy fog or moderate foliage-- blocks vision partially. A creature has disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight to see something in that area.
Is my interpretation of lightly obscured correct?

Be very careful with the fallacy of the inverse when interpreting the rules. Depending on whether you define "lightly obscured" as "visible, to a lesser degree" or "not visible, to a lesser degree", you're going to stumble on different takes. Boiling it down to a mathematical example, the answer to 1/x for x approaching 0 is different whether you approach 0 from the negative side (1/x approaches negative infinity) or the positive side (1/x approaches positive infinity). The same thing applies here when you apply either light or dark logic to what approaches "lightly obscured".

None of the definitions, as written, make sense in every scenario
If you read it as a one-way effect, the definition for heavily obscured only makes sense for darkness anyway. If you're more than a few feet inside an area of opaque fog or dense foliage, things outside it should be equally invisible to you, yet the letter of the rules doesn't make you blinded looking out. If you instead read "blocks vision entirely" to make opaque fog and heavy foliage make sense (so seeing both in and out is impeded), then the rules makes no sense for darkness (if you're within a completely dark cave, you should be able to see a person standing in the cave opening in full sunlight just fine). It's fundamentally broken to try to treat all sorts of obscuring conditions the same.
The DM should rule on a case-by-case basis
This is one of those scenarios where the DM just has to ignore strict readings of the rules and do what seems correct for that particular situation. Generally, obscuring conditions related to light should only affect attempts to see things within the obscured areas. Other forms of obscuring conditions should work symmetrically, except that (in any game I DMed) creatures at the edge of foliage should be allowed to benefit from being obscured from those outside the foliage while still being able to see those outside the foliage (peeking through leaves and the like without revealing themselves).
To be clear, none of this is in the rules. The rules for this are bad (I'm not going to get into house rules here, but the fact that, RAW, two combatants in magical darkness attack each other with neither advantage nor disadvantage is pretty nonsensical, even if there's an argument to be made for it on a "it's more interesting than everyone missing over and over" basis). The DM's job is to make a world that makes sense, and that means making reasonable calls, not trying to read the rules so literally that they end with nonsensical outcomes.

I agree with this, but want to emphasize that there isn't any set of rules for this that would always make sense. Light, vision, and hiding are just very context sensitive.

Heavily obscured for darkness also doesn't make any sense because it doesn't take into account what's behind you. The idea that I can stand in a totally dark tunnel directly in front of the daylight outside and be unseen is a little absurd. I'd be silhouetted against the outside daylight and extremely visible regardless. There's seriously no way to write rules that aren't insanely detailed but always make sense.

@DarthPseudonym: Would the tunnel be totally dark if there's a bright source of light behind you, though? (But yeah, the rules are just weird)

@MatthieuM. Well, if it's daylight, the DM could theoretically rule the whole tunnel is in dim light, but by the rules of light sources, I could have a lantern at the foot of a wall at one end of a hallway, which sheds bright light for 20 feet and dim light for 20 more feet. If you stand 50 feet away, you're in "total darkness", but should still be clearly silhouetted.

@DarthPseudonym: Yeah, the dark tunnel issue is definitely a big problem with even trying to define it into broad categories of light level vs. physical obstructions. Thus, "the DM just has to ignore strict readings of the rules and do what seems correct for that particular situation." In the situation you describe, the center of the tunnel would silhouette the target, but huddling against the walls would likely work for hiding (because there'd be no silhouetting angle for viewers outside the tunnel). Far too complicated for any reasonably concise rules on visibility.

Lightly and heavily obscured work the same
For the rules to make sense, how well you see an object should depend on how much light is on it, not how much light is on you (ignoring the case that if something is dimly lit it should be easier to see if you are also in dim light than if you are in bright light).
And it seems like the (erratummed) version of heavily obscured does just that; "A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area."
But what about lightly obscured?

In a lightly obscured area, such as dim light, patchy fog, or moderate foliage, creatures have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight.

At first glance, it appears that this is the reverse, that this is saying that it is the lighting condition in effect on the creature making the check (and not what is being observed) that is relevant.  But actually, the grammar here is vague.  The sentence can be interpreted multiple ways because it is unclear which noun the preposition "In a lightly obscured area" is supposed to be applied to; "creatures", "checks", or "sight"?  This lack of clarity is because the preposition was placed first in the sentence.  If the preposition had followed the noun it modified (as is more common usage), it would be much clearer.  Consider the difference between:
Creatures [in a lightly obscured area, such as dim light, patchy fog, or moderate foliage] have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight.
and
Creatures have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight [in a lightly obscured area, such as dim light, patchy fog, or moderate foliage].
The first version makes it clear that it is the obscurement where the creatures are that matters, while the second says that it is the obscurement of where the creatures are looking that is important ("sight in a lightly obscured area").  And the actual rule for light obscurement could be interpreted either way.
If you choose the second interpretation, then both light obscurement and heavy obscurement work the same way, basing your Perception on where you are observing, not where you are observing from, and both make sense, so that's what I recommend you do.  This ruling is further supported by the DMG.
In the DMG, the section on Wilderness Survival has a subsection on Weather which includes the phenomena of Heavy Precipitation (110).  This says, in part (emphasis mine):

Everything within an area of heavy rain or heavy snowfall is lightly obscured, and creatures in the area have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight.

Notice the "and" that connects two independent clauses.  The first clause says that the things in the rain or snow are lightly obscured, the second says that in addition observers in the rain or snow have disadvantage on their Perception checks.  If obscurement normally affected the observers rather than the observed, the second clause would both be redundant and should be joined to the first with something like "thus" rather than "and".  As written, the passage in the DMG is telling us that light obscurement affects our ability to see the things in an area regardless of where we are, and that in addition creatures in heavy precipitation have disadvantage on their Perception checks regardless of where the things they are observing are.  The DMG passage supports the interpretation that both heavy and light obscurement work the same way and both are based on the observed, rather than the observer, being in the area of obscurement.

Attempts to make sense
ShadowRanger's answer (heh, heh, ShadowRanger), points out that mundane darkness should not block vision, as the dedicated rule says it does (even though there are other passages in the rules that imply that darkness does not actually block vision).  Unfortunately, the 5e rules on "Vision and Lightning" combine and confound effects that block vision with those that reduce vision, and so are hopelessly muddled, producing illogical effects.
If you are going to houserule your way out of this, I would start by separating things that conceal (fog, foliage, precipitation, magical darkness) from the condition of illumination.  Thus you might have areas that are brightly lit, dimly lit, and unlit, which conditions would affect how well the things in the area can be seen.  These would be independent of areas that are unconcealed, lightly concealed, or heavily concealed, which conditions would affect both an observer in the area and a thing observed in the area - and indeed if an area of such lay in between observer and observed.  And then you would need to rule how these independent conditions interacted with one another.  If it is a brightly lit day but I am standing in an area of light foliage, and trying to see something unconcealed but also under the shade of an awning, how is my Percpetion roll affected?  You could make a detailed system - but in the end, it would be simpler to just go with 5e philosophy; the DM assesses the overall situation, and assigns advantage or disadvantage on the check.

5th edition obscurity rules are ambiguous
You have two types mentioned, but heavy obscurity was fairly quickly were errata'd.

Vision and Light (p. 183). The second sentence of the third paragraph has been changed to “A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition (see appendix A) when trying to see something in that area.”

The previous version meant any creature in a heavily obscured area suffers from the blinded condition, but did not remark about someone trying to see in or out of it.

A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition.

I have to assume they understood the folly of the original rule - someone in a brightly lit area was effectively invisible to someone standing in darkness. They attempted to remedy it with the terse "when trying to see someone in that area" without thinking about the ramifications.
What they failed to do in any case was make the distinction between obscurement from the absence of light and obscurement from something opaque.
Common sense says, if obscurement is from an absence of light, then it doesn't "block" anything, but for someone without extra senses, it's dark within that area. But common sense also says, if thick fog, smoke or magical darkness blocks vision (opaque), then it blocks vision for any trying to see through it, regardless of whether the looker or the target are in the area.
Rule 0 to the rescue
While the rules leave some glaring discrepancies with reality (as you mentioned), you as DM have both the privilege and opportunity to rule as you see fit, where fit is hopefully what makes for a better experience for your players. Consistent rulings are key to providing your players with a sensible and predictable gaming environment.
